# Set the http status code to XXX.X?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http

I know I can set `Response.StatusCode` to an integer value, such as 500. How can I set it to 401.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [SubStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.substatuscode.aspx) property. You should note that setting this property requires running in IIS 7.0 integrated pipeline mode.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`SubStatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.substatuscode.aspx) property